# python login portal with webidentity and forwarding

Tags: python, request

Using Python requests, I am trying to log in a portal url which forwards to another url. I have read several posting on this subject and even tried:

1) create a session with request get and retrieve csrf token

2) use the csrf token from previous step and do a post on portal URL with payload being the username/password / and csrf token (the same info passed when I use developer tools .

3) after step 2 I still get p.text below as enter username and password and does not show the page behind login and indicates it is looking for me to login

```
s = requests.Session()
g = s.get("myPortalURL")
resp = g.text
for item in resp.split("\n"):
    if "csrf_token" in item:
        print (item)
        csrfToken = item.strip().split("value=")[1].replace("\"", "").replace("/>","")

data = {'Username': self.pythonDataDict["portalUsername"], 'Password': self.pythonDataDict["portalPassword"],
           'csrf_token': csrfToken}

print ("payload= ", data)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
p = s.post("myPortalURL", headers=headers, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(p.text)
print (p.text)
```

Comment: Does your `csrf_token` return correctly every time?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible issues with your code:

1. From personal experience; the URL to the login page should be different to the URL for the main page.
2. There is information missing in `data`, **ALL** of the required data needs to be entered in the form,
3. You may need to include additional request headers
4. Your code to get the `csrf_token` could be prone to returning incorrect data depending on the nature of that token (although all tokens vary so it may not)

Also as a side note, it is generally more idiomatic to use a `with` statement when using a session, e.g.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    initial_response = s.get("login_url")
    # def createForm()...
    main_response = s.get("target_url", data = data, headers = headers)
    # rest of code...
```

It would also be extremely helpful if you could include the URL of the page you are trying to access if that is possible.

Comment: Thank join, I really like how you did the request.session. After posting this I realized I need other data as well.